# Angular : When ngModel data is updated from component, UI changes are not changing model value

Tags: angular, checkbox

In an table i have used a checkbox, At any point of time user can select only 2 checkbox. so whenever user selects checkbox i call a function and check if more than 2 checkbox is select, if yes i wil show an error message and change the third checkbox to unchecked state.

After changing checkbox value to unchecked, if i change the checkbox to checked state again from UI, model is not updating

```
<input _ngcontent-c9="" type="checkbox" class="ng-valid ng-dirty ng-touched" ng-reflect-model="false">
```

**ng-reflect-model="false"** this value is not becoming true again.

```
 <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="item.blink" (change)="toggleBlink(item)">
```

```
  private toggleBlink(currentDevice) {
     //conditions to chk if more than 2 checkbox r checked then i m making current one as unchecked
        currentDevice['blink'] = false;

  }
```

How to do this ?

Comment: can you please share your code via [stackblitz](stackblitz.com)

Comment: check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gxmekl-j3wwgm?file=app/select-multiple-example.ts

Comment: so according to your logic if first and third checkbox are selected and user selects second checkbox after that it should not able to do that.

Comment: After clicking on Mushroom i want checkbox to toggle to unchecked state..  since value is false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks Dani and Pranshant :)

I have found the solution. Check the code now

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gxmekl-j3wwgm?file=app%2Fselect-multiple-example.ts

Comment: we need to call below function for the changes to be updated. Check the above link
    this.cdRef.detectChanges();

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a race condition, 
try to replace (change) to (ngModelChange)

Edit:
To resolve race condition you can do a "dirty" setTimeout solution:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gxmekl-j3wwgm

Comment: @user2900572 Check this:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gxmekl-hkeebm working fine here

Comment: when i m changing model value in component why checkbox is not getting unchecked ??

Comment: @user2900572 Can you provide your code in that example? So I can test and check?

Comment: i have modified it https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gxmekl-j3wwgm?file=app%2Fselect-multiple-example.ts

Comment: try to check and uncheck 2nd item.. It keep showing false always but checkbox keeps toggling.. whn value is false it has to come to unchecked state rite? I m missing anything here

Comment: After clicking on Mushroom i want checkbox to toggle to unchecked state..

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean now - there is a "dirty" solution to this one, putting a SetTimeout with interval of 0 where you do the change
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gxmekl-j3wwgm

Comment: Where to add settimeout ?  My concern is since we are making Mushroom value as false... it should always be unchecked.. since its value is always false

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gxmekl-dkrofg
if(i.name ==='Mushroom')
     setTimeout(() => {
        i['blink']=false;
     }, 0);

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to modify the state of check box then (change) event will not help, try (click):

```
<li *ngFor="let item of test; let i = index">
{{item.blink }}
    <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="item.blink" (click)="toggleBlink($event, item)">{{item.name}}
</li>
```

TS:

```
private toggleBlink(event, i) {
  console.log(i);
  if (i.name === "Mushroom") {
    i["blink"] = false;
    // below two lines important to stop checkbox being checked
    event.stopPropagation();
    return false;
  }
  console.log("after changing", i);
}
```

[`Working_Demo`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gxmekl-msqwjz)

Answer (score 0):

i have created an logic to count if any of two checkbox is selected then uncheck third.

```
private toggleBlink(i, val) {
   let count = 0;
       this.test.forEach(value =>{
         // console.log(value);
         if(value.blink === true){
           count++
         }
       })
       console.log(count)
       if(count === 3){
         this.test[i].blink = false;
   }
}
```

but the problem is that ng for doesn't refresh as ng for the only refresh if the array is changed so I change array by its copy.

```
 this.test = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify((this.test)));
```

i am using `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())` so my javascript do not create a **shallow copy**.

here is [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gxmekl-yxvgcy)